# Filter channel entries tag by category url title

Tags: channel-entries, categories

Articles on my site are structured as /[category_url_title]/article/[article_url_title].

Now, I want to have at the bottom of my articles a section that says "related articles", and then list a few more articles from the same category. I have the same template for all articles.

This works perfectly fine:

```
{exp:channel:entries category="100" limit="3" dynamic="off" url_title="not {segment_3}"}
{title}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But I need the category parameter to be set dynamically from {segment_1} which is the category's url title. However, the channel:entries tag will [only accept category id](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#category), not category url title as a parameter.

I have [cat2](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cat2) installed, but this doesn't work:

```
{exp:channel:entries category="{exp:cat2:id category_url_title='{segment_1}'}" limit="3" dynamic="off" url_title="not {segment_3}"}
{title}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I've also tried saving the value of the cat2 tag output as a php variable, but that doesn't work either.

I assume my above efforts don't work because of mixed parse order of EE. So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse a plugin as a parameter, you need to set the parameter `parse` as `inward`.

```
{exp:channel:entries parse="inward" category="{exp:cat2:id category_url_title='{segment_1}'}" limit="3" dynamic="off" url_title="not {segment_3}"}
  {title}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Since different categories on different groups can share the same name, is a good idea to specify the `category_group` parameter on the [cat2](https://github.com/croxton/cat2) add-on.

One more thing. The values of the parameter [`dynamic`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic) should be `yes` or `no`.